# Psionic powers for Aegis

Tags: pathfinder-1e, aegis

When a 4 level Aegis (Elan race) meet prerequisite, he choose "Unlocked Talent" and "Access psionic Talent" so He can access n°5 0-level and a 1-level psionic power. But there are more psionic power lists: Cryptic, Dread, Psion, etc...Nothing for Aegis. From which list the Aegis can pick powers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You don't choose them from *any* list

Unlocked Talent says:

> In addition, when you take this feat, select any one 1st level power

It doesn't come from a class list, it's just any 1st level power that exists.  As long as you don't have features that specifically increase a power's effective level for you (which a single-classed Aegis doesn't) you can take any power that is a 1st level power for pretty much anyone, certainly any power that appears at 1st level on any list.

Access Talent says:

> You gain five psionic talents

So, again, you don't even need a list.  Any psionic talent in the game is fair choice.

Note that none of this is specific to the Aegis-- any character could pick from off 'their' list with these feats.